# Twenty Questions - Programming by Doing

Tags: java

I am looking for a little help. I am sitting at home trying to learn java programming from programmingbydoing.com. I need to make a program called TwentyQuestions. The code is missing something to make it work completely.
I have tried to find help other places on the web. That is why the code looks much like other peoples code.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TwentyQuestions
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        String type, size, guess = "";

        System.out.println("TWO QUESTIONS!");
        System.out.println("Think of an object, and I'll try to guess it.");
        System.out.println("");

        System.out.println("Question 1) Is it animal, vegetable or mineral?");
        System.out.print("> ");
        type = keyboard.next();
        System.out.println("");

        System.out.println("Question 2) Is it bigger than a breadbox?");
        System.out.print("> ");
        size = keyboard.next();
        System.out.println("");

        if (type.equalsIgnoreCase("animal"))
        {
            if (size == "no")
            {
                guess = "squirrel";
            }
            else
            {
                guess = "moose";
            }
        }

        else if (type.equalsIgnoreCase("vegetable"))
        {
            if (size == "no")
            {
                guess = "carrot";
            }
            else
            {
                guess = "watermelon";
            }
        }

        else if (type.equalsIgnoreCase("mineral"))
        {
            if (size == "no")
            {
                guess = "paper clip";
            }
            else
            {
                guess = "Camero";
            }
        }

        if (guess == "")
        {
            System.out.println("The answers provided are not valid. Please try again.");
        }

        else
        {
            System.out.println("My guess is that you are thinking of a " + guess + ".");
            System.out.println("I would ask you if I'm right, but I don't actually care.");
        }
  }
}
```

The problem is that the program does not care about the comparisons that are in the nested if-statements. Control always goes to the `else` and prints that one.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java

Comment: Keep in mind that `size` is a String, and so is  `type`. Compare your `if` statement for `type` (which is working) to the `if` statement for `size` (which isn't working) and the answer will be clear to you. I'd also apply the same logic to `guess`.

Comment: Your first else has a pair of brackets. Since it's not an if else it shouldn't.

Comment: Why do you compare Strings correctly in one part of your code and incorrectly elsewhere? It's as if you're borrowing code but are not understanding it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

when you want to compare Strings you need to use the method *.equals()* or in the case to ignore case *.equalsIgnoreCase()*

Try the code below and you'll see it works just fine.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TwentyQuestions {
public static void main ( String[] args )
{
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    String type, size, guess = "";

    System.out.println("TWO QUESTIONS!");
    System.out.println("Think of an object, and I'll try to guess it.");
    System.out.println("");

    System.out.println("Question 1) Is it animal, vegetable or mineral?");
    System.out.print("> ");
    type = keyboard.next();
    System.out.println("");

    System.out.println("Question 2) Is it bigger than a breadbox?");
    System.out.print("> ");
    size = keyboard.next();
    System.out.println("");

    if (type.equalsIgnoreCase("animal"))
    {
        if (size.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("no"))
        {
            guess = "squirrel";
        }
        else 
        {
            guess = "moose";
        }
    }

    else if (type.equalsIgnoreCase("vegetable"))
    {
        if (size.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("no"))
        {
            guess = "carrot";
        }
        else
        {
            guess = "watermelon";
        }
    }

    else if (type.equalsIgnoreCase("mineral"))
    {
        if (size.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("no"))
        {
            guess = "paper clip";
        }
        else
        {
            guess = "Camero";
        }
    }

    if (guess == "")
    {
        System.out.println("The answers provided are not valid. Please try again.");
    }

    else
    {
        System.out.println("My guess is that you are thinking of a " + guess + ".");
        System.out.println("I would ask you if I'm right, but I don't actually care.");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Douglas.

The `(size.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("no"))` made the difference. The program now works as it should.

Comment: @Christian Helbo, glad to hear. Please, consider checking my answer as a solution!